# How do you make animations not fire unless previous is done (withtout using callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called:

```
this.makeStuffHappen()
```

Which makes different animations according to a switch statement and a couple of variables. Is it possible to make a function not fire unless all previous are done resolving.

I want to write something like

```
$('button').click(function(){
    a.makeStuffHappen();
    b.makeStuffHappen();
    c.makeStuffHappen();
    d.makeStuffHappen();
});
```

And then it should only run b after a is done, c after b is done and d after c is done. Is it only possible to make animations wait for the previous by chaining them? Is it possible to chain any function?

Edit: makeStuffHappen() is animating different elements so a.makeStuffHappen() will animate a different element than b.makeStuffHappen and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback would be the easiest way, but since you don't want to use a callback (which jQuery's `.queue()` does require - well... a recursive callback anyways), you could let the methods you have return a bool:

```
$('button').click(function()
{
    var theObjects = [a,b,c,d];
    for (var i=0;i<theObjects.length;i++)
    {
        if (theObjects[i].makeStuffHappen() === false)
        {
            break;//or throw, or whatever...
        }
    }
});
```

Of course, it is well possible the methods may vary depending on which object is called. You could work around this by using an object instead of an array, in which case your event handler could look something like:

```
$('button').click(function()
{
    var theObjects = {a:'aMethod',b:'bMethod',c:'cMethod'};
    for(var i in theObjects)
    {
        if (theObjects.hasOwnProperty(i))
        {
            if(window[i][theObjects[i]]() === false)
            {
                break;//or throw, or return...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Mind you, I don't know why you don't want to use some form of callback here, as it would be the easiest way to go... but that is, of course, none of my concern... :-)

Well, had a quick look at your game... seems fun, keep working on it :). BTW, you're one step away from using callbacks all over the place:

```
$('#placeBet').click(function() {
    placeBet();
});
```

Can be written as:

```
$('#placeBet').click(placeBet);
```

In the latter, placeBet is a callback function. 
I think you're main concern is here:

```
player.printHand();
dealer.printHand(isDealerHidden);
```

What I'd do here, is change the printHand function, by adding this at the end:

```
if (this.name !== 'dealer')
{
    dealer.printHand(isDealerHidden);
}
```

I haven't read enough of your script to make this work as you need it to, but you get the idea... An easier way would be not to animate the dealer explicitly, but alter all animators of the players hand to end with some code that animates the dealer after the players animation is completed... I know, I'm talking gibberish, but I'm at work... and sick... Good luck, anyway. I might take some more time checking your progress, maybe read your script more closely tonight and edit this dribble to something that will actually work :-)

Comment: Id be happy if you could show me a solution using callback. Im fairly sure you know more than me :)

Comment: I'm trying to think of a helpful example, but I can't... I need a bit more info: are objects `a`,`b`... DOM elements? Do you know what callback functions are? And what exactly is it that `makeStuffHappen()` does? if you want a callback approach, you could setup a jsFillde?

Comment: Your second way won't work. `i` will be either `a`, `b` or `c` and `theObjects[i]` will return a string `'aMethod'`, `'bMethod'`, ... You cannot *call* a string.

Comment: @Felix: you're right, it should read `window[i][theObjects[i]]()`, then it'll work

Comment: Well im doing a blackjack game (for hobby) and im basicly done with the game without animations. You can see the game at crossfat.dk/bj. You can see where im at as far as animations go at crossfat.dk/bjAnimated. The problem is that I have no clue on how to go about it, making sure that one animation doesnt fire without the prvious being done unless I chain them and I have no idea how I'd chain them when the animations can be so different depending on which hand and card is being animated.

Even in the current state, I still need a way to make the dealers hand is be dealt after the players

Comment: Thanks a lot! I definetly need to read up on callback functions, and I also think I need to make an animate function which animates every thing instead of having a dealer.printHand and player.printHand. But it does annoys me that if you have animations inside loops that the loop will continue even thou the animation isnt done.

Comment: That's where callbacks come in, m8! look for a few examples of JavaScript's `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` methods... will prove usefull, I promise :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (or at least most flexible) way would be using [deferred objects *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). For that you have to return a deferred object from each function, for example:

```
a.makeStuffHappen = function() {
    elementA.animate(...);
    elementB.animate(...);
    ...


    return $.when(elementA, elementB,...);
};
```

Same for `b.makeStuffHappen`, etc.

[`$.when()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) returns a deferred object where you can attach callbacks to which are executed once all deferred objects passed to it are resolved.

Then in your event handler, you can call [`.pipe()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) on these deferred objects, to chain them together:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    a.makeStuffHappen()
       .pipe($.proxy(b.makeStuffHappen, b))
       .pipe($.proxy(c.makeStuffHappen, c))
       .then(function() {
           console.log('All done');
       });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4f7EZ/)

Comment: @Zecc: Well, yeah, in a way, but there is no other way to chain functions.

Comment: True. But I get the feeling the questioner wants a solution that prevents callbacks in the calling code, which is why I'm thinking `makeStuffHappen` should be the function managing all the queueing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was asking the question in a very bad way. Ive only been coding for 2 month so im simply just bad at it. I've been making a blackjack game (for hobby), the game without animation is at crossfat.dk/bj and with animation at crossfat.dk/bjAnimated/ . My current solution(unfininshed) works, but its very ugly in my opinion. I dont expect you to take your time to look at it, but migth aswell post it anyway. I basicly have a this.printHand() function which check if cards in an array have been added to the DOM and animated and if the cards arent in the dom will add it and animate it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jquery's queue function:
[http://api.jquery.com/queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a callback function to your method :

```
this.makeStuffHappen = function(callback)  {
   //do things like animations
   $(this).animate({ ... }, 200, callback);
   //or call the callback after everything is done:
   callback();
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    a.makeStuffHappen(b.makeStuffHappen(c.makeStuffHappen(d.makeStuffHappen())));
});
```